# Trouble With Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am currently trying to access a website in my application through Selenium and Python. I need to copy an address from a website. To do this you must click on the copy button on the website which will copy the full address to your clipboard.

This is what I have so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://opensea.io/accounts/sartoshi_nft')
driver.execute_script("document.body.style.transform='scale(0.5)';")

action = ActionChains(driver)

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div[1]/div/div/main/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/button[2]/i')

action.double_click(on_element = elem)
action.perform()

print(action)
```

I can see that it is going to the website and copying the value I want, but how can I actually return that value back to my application in Python?

Comment: do you want to use the clipboard (copy/paste?) or do you just want the information?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are correct that the text has been copied, you can use python's `clipboard` module to access that data, like this:

```
import clipboard
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://opensea.io/accounts/sartoshi_nft')
driver.execute_script("document.body.style.transform='scale(0.5)';")

action = ActionChains(driver)

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div[1]/div/div/main/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/button[2]/i')

action.double_click(on_element = elem)
action.perform()

print(clipboard.paste())
```